# Need to calculate time with seconds from multiple times values in PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I has an array in php

```
Array (
    [0] => 07:50:15-i
    [1] => 10:55:41-i
    [2] => 12:33:30-i
    [3] => 12:34:04-i
    [4] => 14:32:57-i
    [5] => 14:32:59-i
    [6] => 15:30:50-i
    [7] => 10:29:27-o
    [8] => 12:06:16-o
    [9] => 14:29:10-o
    [10] => 14:29:12-o
    [11] => 15:02:28-o
    [12] => 16:57:31-o
)
```

Values which ends with `-i` value means an intime value
and `-o` value means an outtime value

How i can calculate the total Intime by just taking multiple outtime(s)- multiple intime(s)

I need to calculate the total Intime (if all the times sorted as ascending order) like if there are multiple intimes before an outtime only last intime should be considered for calculation. Like that if there are multiple outtimes before an intime only last outtime should be considered for calculation.

Edit 1: Added some more values so intimes and outimes happened twice at same time

Comment: I'm having issues following how this should be calculated. Please give examples of inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: First get your array into a useful format though, convert your string to a time, then apply the logic required. This isn't a question we're going to hand hold you through as we can't see any examples of code.

Comment: @Shane I too confused how to get that but these times are in an out times grabbed from an BioMetric machine and i need to calculate the exact intime which can exclude the break times

Comment: @KMKMAHESH Not sure how you're supposed to reliably match up an in time with an out time to calculate how long it was "in," when you have consecutive in/out times. How can one machine go "in" twice before going out? Maybe there is a better way this data can be retrieved instead of a flat array. Or maybe how the data is stored needs to be improved.

Comment: @Shane Multiple intimes or outtimes is possible because after a punch he not crossed the door so he need to punch more to cross the door.  About the data it is the data collected from two places of a script so i cant manipulate the existing unless i get the perfect code which can helps better than this

Comment: @KMKMAHESH So, in the case of him punching in twice, then punching out twice, what should the total time be?

Comment: @Shane That is thing i need to script, last incoming and last outgoing should be consider for calculation if multiple punches occured.  And i am not sure how i can sort that array which contain strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to calculate the total time spent "inside".

```
$times = array( // sample data
    "07:50:15-i",
    "10:55:41-i",
    "12:33:30-i",
    "12:34:04-i",
    "14:32:57-i",
    "14:32:59-i",
    "15:30:50-i",
    "10:29:27-o",
    "12:06:16-o",
    "14:29:10-o",
    "14:29:12-o",
    "15:02:28-o",
    "16:57:31-o"
);

sort($times); // get times in order

$in = false;  // state
$incur = 0;   // current intime
$intotal = 0; // total time spent inside
foreach ($times as $key => $time)
{
  // match timestamp and -i/-o
  // $m[1] will be the time
  // $m[2] will be -i/-o
  preg_match('/^([0-9:]+)(-i|-o)$/', $time, $m);

  if ($m[2] === '-i')
  {
    $in = true; // set state
    $incur = strtotime($m[1]); // memorize time
  }
  else if ($m[2] === '-o' && $in &&
    ( // look ahead for more -o or end of array
      (isset($times[$key + 1]) && substr($times[$key + 1], -2, 2) !== '-o')
      || !isset($times[$key + 1])
    )
  )
  {
    $in = false; // set state
    $intotal += strtotime($m[1]) - $incur; // add delta
  }
}

echo "Total time inside: {$intotal} seconds (= "
    . $intotal/60/60 . " hours or " . $intotal/60 . " minutes)";
```

produces

> Total time inside: 27665 seconds (= 7.6847222222222 hours or 461.08333333333 minutes)

for your sample data.

Comment: i will try this

Comment: If Multiple intimes it is working but for Multiple outtimes  is not working.

Comment: @KMKMAHESH ah, now I understand, I updated my answer. There is now a lookahead to check for following out times.

Comment: Answer accepted and Upvoted. You made my day thanks for help